# ReactJS "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.state.features.map is not a function"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

I'm learning React and now I'm trying to do a get request and list with map but when I run this code they come up with this error "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.state.features.map is not a function". I have already searched this but I do not understand what is going on.

```
   import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      features: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Test',
        count: 1
      }]
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch("http://demo6085176.mockable.io/features")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        console.log(json);
        this.setState({
          features: json,
        });
      });
    console.log(this.state.features)
      
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          {
            this.state.features.map(function(feature){
              return (
                <li key={feature.id}><button type="button">Upvote</button> ({feature.count}) <span>{feature.name}</span></li>
              )
            })
          }
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: What says console.log(json) ?

Comment: 'json' is not defined

Comment: You have to wait until `fetch` finishes... set something like "loading..." and after fetch is done, map it

Comment: Your problem is solved through proper debugging. Given that `json` is undefined when you `console.log` it, then there may be something wrong with the server's output.

Comment: @AndreLi not agree, he doesn't need to wait until fetch.

Comment: @SalatielQueiroz change setState({features: json}) to setState({features:json.features}), this should work

Comment: @EvgenySorokin Thank you! I change it and works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your componentWillMount, just do this:

```
componentWillMount() {
   fetch("http://demo6085176.mockable.io/features")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => {
      console.log(json);
      this.setState({ features: json.features });
   });
}
```

The response you get from the API is an object which has a key of `features` which is an array of objects of the data you want.